# In Sass, how to compare two or more values in if statement?

Tags: if-statement, sass

I know that in PHP I can do something like this:

```
if ($foo == true && $bar == true) {
    // Both true
} elseif ($foo == false && $bar == false) {
    // Both false
}
```

How could I do that in Sass? Or can I... The docs are sparse on this topic http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_6

I tried something like this:

```
@if $foo == false $bar == false {
    // Both false
}
```

Doesn't give error but it only evaluates the `$foo`.

This also wont work:

```
@if $foo == false && $bar == false {
    // Both false
}
```

Nor this:

```
@if $foo == false AND $bar == false {
    // Both false
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [§6.4.4 - Boolean Operations](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#boolean_operations):

> SassScript supports `and`, `or`, and `not` operators for boolean values.

Comment: Thank you sir, I don't know how I missed that.